# JAR is not getting embedded in the OSGi bundle when using embedded dependencies

Tags: maven, osgi, osgi-bundle

I have a requirement to embed a non-osgi third party dependency (nimbus-jose-jwt) for a custom use-case.

I have added the following dependency under the dependencies section in pom file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
    <artifactId>nimbus-jose-jwt</artifactId>
    <version>5.8</version>
</dependency>
```

I have tried embedding the third party jar within the bundle using the Embed-Dependency directive.

```
<Embed-Dependency>
    com.nimbusds.jose.*;scope=compile|runtime;inline=true,
    com.nimbusds.jwt.*;scope=compile|runtime;inline=true,
</Embed-Dependency>
```

My maven-bundle-plugin in the pom file looks as follows.

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
            <instructions>
                <Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    ${project.artifactId}
                </Bundle-SymbolicName>

                <Private-Package>

                </Private-Package>
                <Import-Package>

                </Import-Package>
                <Export-Package>

                </Export-Package>
                <Embed-Dependency>
                    com.nimbusds.jose.*;scope=compile|runtime;inline=true,
                    com.nimbusds.jwt.*;scope=compile|runtime;inline=true,
                </Embed-Dependency>
                <Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>
            </instructions>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

The resulting manifest is correct but the jar is not embedded inside the
bundle. What more should I do to have it embedded in my bundle? Appreciate any help on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
<Embed-Dependency>*;scope=compile|runtime;inline=true;artifactId=nimbus-jose-jwt</Embed-Dependency>
```

or

```
<Embed-Dependency>nimbus-jose-jwt;scope=compile|runtime;inline=true</Embed-Dependency>
```

The matching expression, at least the first one, matches artifact IDs, not package names. Have a look at the [bundle plugin documentation](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html#embedding-dependencies) for more info on how to select artifacts for embedding.